# How to read the exact bytes of the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

def XoR(filename, operand): 
   byte = bytearray(1024)    
   with open(filename, "rb") as file:    
      reAd = file.readinto(byte)    
      while True:    
         reAd = file.readinto(byte)    
         for i in range(reAd):    
            byte[i] ^= operand
         sys.stdout.buffer.write(byte)

def main():   
   return XoR(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':   
   main()
```

I am not sure how should i modify my code so that the total number of bytes of the output is exactly same as the total number of bytes in the input file.
Based on my code, the output was the multiple of 1024 which is the initial size of the buffer.
What can i do so that it outputs the relevant bytes in the last block instead of the whole chunk of buffer? Should i create a condition to handle the last block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Option 1:** Only write as many bytes back to the file as the `readinto` operation returned.

  ```
  sys.stdout.buffer.write(byte[:reAd])
  ```
- **Option 2:** Don't use `readinto`.

  ```
  def XoR(filename, operand):  
      with open(filename, "rb") as file:
          while True:    
              chunk = file.read(1024)
              if not chunk:
                  break

              chunk = bytes(byte ^ operand for byte in chunk)
              sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk)
  ```